# Filter term taxonomy metabox in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, filters, wp-admin

I have created a custom post type games and registered taxonomy game-filter.

When creating game-filter I am adding "is_deleted" in term meta.

Now, when creating a game, I want to display only those game filters having is_deleted = 0.

[image]

I tried many things but was not able to fix this.